# Banana peel trope: where does it come from?

Tags: trope

I read [on TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BananaPeel) that:

> The use of a banana peel as an injurious prop is actually alarmingly
>   realistic and a reference to its ubiquity on the streets of American
>   cities in the early part of the 20th Century. Refrigeration and
>   shipping speed had combined to make bananas the most popular fruit in
>   the country, and in that age before anti-littering laws, people would
>   just eat the fruit and discard the peels wherever they were. As they
>   rotted, the peels would become quite slippery and thus dangerous to
>   tread upon.

(btw, is that true?), but I wonder: who used it first in a gag?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_peel) starts with 1854 - so it was a pre-film era joke.

Comment: [This amazingly detailed link](http://esnpc.blogspot.com/2014/12/a-slippery-history-of-banana-peel-gag.html) will answer all your questions, and then some (Long story short: They first appeared in film around 1913-15, on stage around 1900, and in written jokes in the last half of the 19th century)

Comment: I'm not so sure of the veracity of your source: (1) refrigeration was available long before the 20th century (witness Aussie beef in England) and (2) bananas are shipped green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=slipping-on-a-banana-peel&sort=year,asc&mode=detail&page=1) has a own keyword *"Slipping On A Banana Peel" Titles* and it mention as first film [The Flirt (1917)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0007956/). You can check the sketch at [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIJygFYiDHw).

But the list is uncomplete, e.g. one of the best banana scenes [The Battle of the Century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Battle_of_the_Century) (1927) is missing.

So I'm sure there are older films with at least a short banana scene.

Comment: ... but the trope doesn't originate with film, as the link in the comment above points out.